# angularjs filter not working with $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular.js, but I cannot figure out how to make | filter:xxx  work with data generated through $http service.

In the following code, I simply cannot get the filter to work with data generated by $http - it simply does nothing when I type inside input box. However, the filter DOES WORK if I hard code some data inside $scope function.

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">

    <input ng-model="search">
    <ul>

        <li ng-repeat="user in users| filter:search">
            {{user.id}}
            {{user.firstname}}
            {{user.lastname}}
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>

function UserCtrl($scope, $http) {
$http.get('actions.php?action=get_user_list').success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
  });

}

</script>
```

Comment: Figured out what it is - my php script was generating JSON array of objects with a key (i.e. 01 => array (...). Angular cannot filter this properly.  The solution is to generate a list of objects without a key, for example: $output=array(array(data),array(data)) etc.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful for you: `array_values` strips keys, so array becomes simple 0-based, well, array.

Comment: Yup, an angular filter only works with arrays.

Comment: The filter in fact works with objects, not just arrays | filter: {name: search}

Comment: @pvukovic You should post your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This can serve you:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users| filter:{firstname : search}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey test with below codes

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl>
    <input ng-model="search">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search.$">
            {{user.id}}
            {{usesr.firstname}}
            {{user.lastname}}
    </ul>
</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module('Your Module Name' ,[]);

app.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('actions.php?action=get_user_list').then(function(response){
        $scope.users = response.data;
    });
});

</script>
```