# How do I get an objFilter for working with integers within Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have been looking at this for some time now. stukennedy's answer to [angularjs filter (not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672614/angularjs-filter-not-working) has helped me get a bunch of things working. 
Now I am having issues trying to get more functionality.
I am trying to filter data which is coming in as an integer, however the filter is not working, I am assuming because HTML value is giving a string and it is not the same.

```
<select ng-model="objects.level">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
```

Further where I have my data:

```
<ul class="items">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items | objFilter:objects" >
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And the objFilter

```
app.filter('objFilter', function() {
  return function(items, filter) {
      if (!filter){
          return items;
      }  
      var result = {};
        angular.forEach( filter, function(filterVal, filterKey) {
          angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
              var fieldVal = item[filterKey];
              if (fieldVal && fieldVal.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterVal.toLowerCase()) > -1){
                  result[key] = item;
              }
          });
        });
        return result;
    };
});
```

As the data is coming in from an API I have no control over the data I am recieving. I am using the objFilter elsewhere on the same list for string values without issue. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: just a suggestion : you can do if-else on the basis of typeof `fieldVal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really tuff to understand what the problem is without having a look a the "objects" object, as well as some data for the "items" object.
That said, I've made a an example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wgsff22a/) of using some port of your custom filter, but making it a bit simpler where the "Select" component is to filter the "level" attribute of the items.

Basically the custom filter is iterating through the "objects" value and filter all the values in the items that answers any attribute of the filter. 
So if you select 1 on the component, since the value of this attribute is "level":

```
<select ng-model="objects.level">
```

The final value will only select the first item:

```
{name:"bla", level:1}
```

Since its level is the same as the object's value.
Have a look at the example I believe it will help you understand it better..
Good luck!

Comment: This is almost perfect. Thank you for your assistance. I am still trying to get my head around Angular. What would I need to add to be able to return all items when ALL is selected? I imagine just an else statement somehow?