# Filtering nested objects in ng-repeat with a search input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter nested objects in ng-repeat by using a search textbox.

Given the following object:

```
$scope.items = {
    "1": {
        name: "First Item",
        tag: "first"
    },
    "2": {
        name: "Second Item",
        tag: "second"
    }
};
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="serchBox" ng-model="searchByName">
<p ng-repeat="(key, values) in items | filter:{name: searchByName}">
    Using both {{key}} and {{values.name}}
</p>
```

This is indeed not working. I tried a lot of things and I couldn't make it work properly. **I don't want to change my object.** I was searching a lot but I didn't find anything that fits my needings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally got the answer to my own question.

I only had to create my own filter and check if the properties inside the object have the desired value by using regular expressions:

```
app.filter('customSearchFilter', function() {
return function(input, term) {
    var regex = new RegExp(term || '', 'i');
    var obj = {};
    angular.forEach(input, function(v, i){
      if(regex.test(v.name + '')){
        obj[i]=v;
      }
    });
    return obj;
  };
});
```

And apply it in the HTML this way:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchName" />
<ul>      
  <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in items | customSearchFilter:searchName">Both {{key}} and {{val.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I created this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/102OVKZ4SLKUypoRDqBk?p=preview) to show my solution in action

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to reuse your filter anywhere else, you can write your filtering function in controller.

```
scope.customSearchFilter = function(term){
    return function(item) {
        var regex = new RegExp(term || '', 'i');
        return regex.test(item.name + '');
    };
};
```

Filter argument is a single item, not an array.

Here is examples. 1st variant is with model, and 2nd with plain scope:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ELH8S5GymG8cHfOJqD9G

Comment: The item is an array inside the filter, and when we edit the filter function in the Plunker to pass the parameters the way you have suggested it doesn't work. Also, by changing the function from a new filter to a scope variable a "Circular dependency" error is thrown. Could you provide a living example where your solution works as expected?

Comment: It's a good practice to use dot in your variable names, like `ctrl.items`. Guess your errors is caused by variable conflicts. I'll update my answer with examples.

Comment: Your example shows an **array** of objects, while what I meant was an **object** of objects. That is not the original purpose of this question, so the example is invalid.

Comment: Well, your question doesn't point to the core of your problem. My example filtering nested objects. Objects of array. The first thing is - ng-repeat doesn't support an objects. So maybe it will be simplier to convert yout object into array? Anyway, my point was only about an alternative way of filtering. Not the answer candidate. :D

Comment: I wrote the object explicitly in the question trying to avoid a confusion with an array of objects. I wanted to filter an object so as not to have to convert any variable of my code :) Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!