# AngularJS filter not working on two or more items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am displaying the list of incidents on the page using AngularJS.(It works)

I also have 3 buttons on the page. 'Open'-shows open incidents, 'Closed' -shows closed incidents, 'All' -shows all incidents.(It works)

Issue: when I try to set the page default to show only "Open incidents", when the users opens the page.

Note: By using below code, I am able to set the page default to "Open incidents", when the list have 1 incident. But, if it have more than 1 incident, the code is not working and showing empty page.

I am putting the total code in plunker. As I am using this code in a Tool, it is not possible to run this code in plunker. The tool have separate script to get all the incidents in JSON format. I am also attaching the JSON format in JSON file. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<div class="myRequests">

  <div class="row" ng-repeat="inc in IncItems | filter:{status: IncStatus}">
    <div class="panel panel-default {{inc.status}}">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">{{inc.number}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-3 pace">
          <p><b>Status:</b> {{inc.status}}</p>
          <p><b>State:</b>{{inc.state}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Plunker: [My code](http://plnkr.co/edit/cGpEwO1laGU1BuayStZv?p=preview)

Comment: Don't you see any errors on the `log` ?

Comment: @Korte I see no errors on log.

Comment: I made a plunker with the code equal to yours and it seems to be working. http://embed.plnkr.co/M2KTj0EUWTfeDPdMexPM/

Comment: @Korte I saw your code. Its work, but in my case it is not working. Your passing array to the filter. But in my case, as object. I saw this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672614/angularjs-filter-not-working

Comment: It is possible to do ng-repeat through an object of objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743724/filtering-nested-objects-in-ng-repeat-with-a-search-input-field/41743725#41743725