# Angular Filter with | filter{datatype:object.properties} is not seeing any data when adding this filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I am used to writing custom filters and now that I been banging my head with ng-options in the dropdowns I was switching to ng-repeat within selects

Seems that when I add in a filter like this below I no longer get data

```
<select id="Utility" name="Utility" class="form-control" required>
    <option ng-repeat="utility in detail.utilityList | filter:{type:detail.utilityList}"  ng-value="utility.name">{{utility.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The detail.UtilityList has a `type` so I'm confused

```
  $scope.detail.utilityList = [{
     "name": "Commonwealth Edison Co",
     "type": "Electric",
     "$$hashKey": "object:140"
  }, {
     "name": "Nicor Gas",
     "type": "Gas"
  }, {
     "name": "Peoples Energy",
     "type": "Gas"
  }];
```

Here is a fiddle that shows it all

https://jsfiddle.net/e8o3ef35/

1. Do I even need to use an `ng-model`  ?  what is the purpose?
2. Can `ng-options` really be a better way to go?
3. Is the reason I need to use `$scope`,  is is because i'm not using the `controller as` syntax?
4. I did want to use the  `detail.utilityType`   that with filter didn't work either

> here is the other

```
 $scope.detail.utilityType = [
 {
    "type": "Gas"
 }, 
 {
    "type": "Electric"
 }];
```

Comment: As summarize, what do you need? Is that when the user select an option of the first select (`utilityList / type`) should filter the other select (`programList`)? Something like this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/3a8az16L/1/) (is just an example, not the final code). I could give you a clean and correct answer if you tell me what is the desired behavior.

Comment: yes, somewhat,  i'm looking for more various ways of doing select dropdowns with ng-options various ways of doing it,  I have this other detail.utilityType that I would like to use to end up filtering ,  I suppose that the one with only gas and electric needs to be its own dropdown select and then when say electric is selected from that new 1st dropdown that it "triggers with angular to cascade on down ,  so if you could show me an answer with that,  i'd greatly appreciate it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually for what as you said in comments that you want to show first dropdown only for UtilityType and then based on selected Utility Type you want to show another dropdown having values of Utilitylist based on selected type.

Here is the code :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form>
    <div >
        Select Utility Type
        </div>
        <select id="type" name="Type" class="form-control" required ng-model="selectedType">
            <option ng-repeat="type in detail.utilityType " ng-value="type.type">{{type.type}}</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-if="selectedType">
        Selected Type is : {{selectedType}}
        </div>
        <br>
        <div ng-if="selectedType">
        Select Utility List
        </div>
        <select id="list" name="List" class="form-control" required ng-if="selectedType" ng-model="selectedutility">
            <option ng-repeat="utility in detail.utilityList| filter:{type:selectedType}" ng-value="utility.name">{{utility.name}}</option>
        </select>

    </form>
</div>
```

You need to first pick up selected type from first dropdown and then apply filter on second dropdown based on selected type.

Comment: yes,  that seems to be in the right direction , thx    here is my updated fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/sa7umjo1/

Comment: you can create your own filter as done in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743724/filtering-nested-objects-in-ng-repeat-with-a-search-input-field